# Titanium layout

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

In a titanium mobile app, I have a scroll view with objects that are 25% of the screen width, trying to create a 'table' of these objects, with 4 columns and however many rows. Is there a way to have the parent scrollView lay these out in such a manner? I tried both vertical and horizontal layouts on the scrollView, but neither gave the desired layout.

Comment: I Think you want to do show 4 tableview in one window right!

Comment: @MRT Right, except I want them to all scroll at once.

Comment: do they need to scroll independently?

Comment: @xtremerunnerars yes, and Jay's answer seems to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the thing that you are looking for is scrolling 4 tableviews/scrollviews at once. This module should help you: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/tandemscroll/mobile/ios

Look at this sample code how to use the Titanium module: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/tandemscroll/mobile/ios/example/app.js

I don't know if this would work with tableviews, but you can use a scrollview and imitate the behavior of a tableview and build your custom function to fake rows. But you can experiment with that and see what will be best for you.

Tandemscroll is a module that will allow you to lock the scrolling of multiple scrollviews, which should be perfect for your case.